# Duvidas no funcionamento de uma tarefa CRON, Não e como AGENDAR e sim o FUNCIONAMENTO da mesma

Tags: linux, cron

Estou com uma dúvida em um agendamento de tarefas no CRON e gostaria de mais esclarecimentos no funcionamento dela.

Se tenho uma tarefa a ser executada a cada minuto, e esta tarefa por exemplo demore mais que 1 minuto, EX: tenho um relatório com mais de 20 mil linhas e a execução de uma rotina percorrer 15 mil linhas e executar uma tarefa de comparação demora  dois minuto.

Ai o o Agendamento CRON esta programado para executar novamente nos próximos 60 segundos.

A tarefa agendada anteriormente para ou finaliza? Mesmo que a segunda tenha sido chamada.

Lembrando que este é sé um exemplo acima para saber como funciona, e a duvida não e como Agendar e sim como funciona a fila

Comment: Acredito, não tenho certeza, que o cron vai apenas iniciar aquele processo em determinados períodos, ou seja, as tarefas vão ir acumulando, se levar 2min na metade do tempo outra tarefa irá iniciar. Isso não é muito recomendável já que pode haver conflitos e, depois de algum tempo, sobrecarregar o servidor

Comment: Depois de ler aqui: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab, não terá mais dúvidas.

Comment: Entendi, vou ver o que consigo aqui pos sempre tera que finalizar um processo para iniciar o seginte, vou ver o que mais consigo para evitar este atropelo caso ele exista

Answer (score 0):

O cron respeita o agendamento que você fez, se está de 1 em 1 minuto, ele irá iniciar o script de 1 em 1 minuto independentemente da execução anterior ter finalizado.

Você pode, em seu script ou programa, implementar uma fila ou algo do tipo que faça o processo seguinte ficar aguardando o final da execução.

Comment: Eu também acho isso Juliano, tomara que de certo, vou testar aqui e ver o que vai dar, e o bom e que não corre risco de embolar a fila pq ele vai apagando os processos finalizados!